# Under which terms would $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}f\left(x^{2}\right)dx $ converge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

let $ f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ be continious function.

Originally I had to tell which demands on $ f $ would make sure that the integral $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}f\left(x^{2}\right)dx $ would converge.

There's just one demand that I cant decide yet.

So, I'll arrange the question:

Assume $ f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ continious function,

and assume that exists $ 0<T\in\mathbb{R} $ such that for any $ 1\leq x $ it follows that $ f\left(x+T\right)=f\left(x\right) $.

In addition assume that $ \intop_{1}^{1+T}f\left(x\right)dx=0 $.

Under those terms, is it true that $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}f\left(x^{2}\right)dx $ converges?

I'm stuck on this one, and dont really have a good idea. So any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's criterion?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know. How do you use it here?

Comment: Make the substitution $u = x^2$, then look at your condition and Dirichlet.

Comment: @DanielFischer $ \intop_{1}^{u}f\left(x^{2}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\intop_{1}^{u}\frac{f\left(t\right)}{\sqrt{t}}dt $, Do you mean that I should use here the fact that $ \intop_{1}^{u}f\left(t\right)dt $ is bounded and $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} $ is monotonic?>

Comment: Yes. And $1/\sqrt{t}$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(y) := \int_1^y f(s)\, ds$, $y\geq 1$. From the assumptions on $f$ it is easy to verify that $F$ is bounded, i.e. there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|F(y)| \leq C$ for every $y\geq 1$.

Using the change of variable $y=x^2$ and integrating by parts we have that, for every $b > 1$,
$$
\int_1^b f(x^2)\, dx = \int_1^{b^2} \frac{f(y)}{2 \sqrt{y}}\, dy
= -\left.\frac{F( y)}{2\sqrt{y}}\right|_1^{b^2} +\int_1^{b^2}\frac{F(y)}{y^{3/2}}\, dy.
$$
Since $F$ is bounded, the function $F(y) / y^{3/2}$ is absolutely integrable in $[1, +\infty)$, hence the r.h.s.  converges for $b\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes, sure (I had made an explicit calculation for $\sin(x^2)$ before.)